# .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages Login/Authentication in Containers / Load Balancers

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, microservices, razor-pages, aws-fargate

I am building a new app using .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages, hosted in AWS Fargate Docker instances, and I'm not sure how to handle logins and authentication.

My first attempt used the traditional login method with Claims, hoping that maybe it would "just work".

It does work with a single task/container, even behind the load balancer, but falls apart when the Fargate cluster scales to more than one task.  The HTTP response code is 400 Bad Request.

I was expecting this problem because it's cookie-based, but I cannot find any examples of the correct way to implement Razor Page authentication in a microservice/docker/load balanced situation.

Is there a way to configure the cookie to use JWT tokens or something?  Or some magic .NET options to turn on somewhere that will make it work?  How do I get authentication to work in this scenario?  Some special middleware?

**Edit 1**: Also, the ideal scenario lets me store the credentials in the database like I normally would, I just need to validate their info and then create whatever kind of cookie/token that will work with Razor Pages in a load-balanced / Fargate/Docker containerized scenario.

**Edit 2**
I was able to at least stop the 400 Bad Request error by adding the `IgnoreAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` to the `AddRazorPagesOptions` section. I found this on https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification.  I'm sure this is a "horrible idea", but gives some clues as to what's going on.  The behavior now is that it appears to log in, but the next request ends up on a different container (I think) which thinks I am not logged in and dumps me back to login:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/admin");
        options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

**Current "Authentication"**

```
if (UserName == "test" && Password == "1234")
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName)
    };
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
    return RedirectToPage("/admin/index");
}
```

Comment: You got a 400, not a 401? Weird. I have limited experience with Razor Pages, but I know from personal experience that using .NET Core with JWTs is easy as pie (at least in .NET Core + React). Take a look at these gists: https://gist.github.com/baughmann/b9b921cf5761e6214b8e5fdd039aa706 & https://gist.github.com/baughmann/38d5fc47b98fce6953e334c07b53f76d. As long as your client sends the JWT Bearer in the header, and it was signed using the same key, is sent to the same domain name, and the token isn't expired, it should work no matter which instance it hits.

Comment: @Nickdb93 Those examples are for Web API/Angular/React/etc scenarios though, right?  Can a browser-based Razor Pages app be configured so that it will use a bearer token and not a cookie?

Comment: @FirstDivison Yes, you're correct. I'm doing some research now to try to find an example with Razor Pages. There definitely has to be an option.

Comment: @FirstDivision Still looking around, but it appears your best bet may still be cookies. It looks like passing JWTs in the header might be best used for external calls (such as a separated client side, as is the case with React or a third party API). I'll keep looking though. In the meantime, see if you can clean any useful info from this: https://amanagrawal.blog/2017/09/18/jwt-token-authentication-with-cookies-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @FirstDivision I would explore saving the token if I were you. It would look like `options.savetoken` under `AddJWTBearer()` in the gist I posted. Read more here: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-jwt-saving-bearer-token-as-claim/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationproperties?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It has to be something like in "the old days" you could set the machine key that would allow the same application cookie to validate on different machines. So, something like an Environment Variable that each Docker instance would use to validate the cookie?  My guess is the solution will be the same as for a "traditional" MVC app...whatever that is. This is one of those "this can't be that hard" things that will end up being a "magic options switch" in startup.cs.

Comment: @Nickdb93 I forgot to tag you in my previous comment and missed the edit window.  Thanks again!

Comment: @KirkLarkin I did see that, and read through a bunch of it.  I had read some of it before when dealing with the GKE load balancer too (the x-forwarded-for headers). Was there a part that you had in mind for my situation?  Is it the Distributed Cache / Redis section?  I did see that and put it on the back burner while I hunted for what I figured had to be an easier method to quickly get up and running.  If that's the only way to get it to work then I suppose I'll have to go down that road, but it felt overkill for the simple thing I'm trying to build.

Comment: It’s all about the data protection keys. They need to match on all hosts but by default they’re saved to a local folder, which ends up with each host using a different key. Resolve that and you’ll also be able to re-enable the CSRF protection, which relies on the same mechanism. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2) explains all.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks, I'll dig into that and see if I can get it going.

Answer (score 1):

I'd still like to find a more generic solution, but for now this satisfies my immediate needs.  I don't like how it ties me to AWS S3, so if anyone has a better solution that's more code-based and uses something like `Environment Variables` I'd love to see it.

I found this Nuget package:
https://github.com/hotchkj/AspNetCore.DataProtection.Aws

Configuration is easy.  You'll need some usings:

```
using AspNetCore.DataProtection.Aws.S3;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon;
```

Then in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("my-mvc-app") //required so that all container apps have the same name
    .PersistKeysToAwsS3(
        new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1), //I had to specify the endpoint or else I got an exception
        new S3XmlRepositoryConfig("my-mvc-app-data-protection-keys") //the name of the bucket you create in S3
        {
            KeyPrefix = "DataProtectionKeys/", //optional KeyPrefix (i.e. subfolder in S3)
        });
```

In that code example above I would have had to go to S3 and create a new bucket called "my-mvc-app-data-protection-keys" and then inside that create a new folder called "DataProtectionKeys"

Furthermore, the IAM execution role acount that is used to run your Fargate Task must have the following permissions to S3:

- s3:GetObject
- s3:ListBucket
- s3:PutObject

Comment: If you're using keys stored in AWS, why can't you just use a key stored in AWS or in your appsettings.json (assuming all instances have the same config file)